# update a field from an object when a 'Note' is deleted

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update, notes

I want to write a trigger on 'Note' object, what the trigger should do is:-

1. I have a object called Incident__c and a custom field called Notes__c (Long Text Area).
2. Whenever a Note get created(In the Incident__c object record), Notes__c field should be updated with Note body.
3. When there are many Notes created, Notes__c field should append with all Note bodies.
4. Also, when an existing 'Note' is edited, edited value should be updated in the Notes__c field.

My code provided below is doing what I want.

I want to update the Notes__c field, when a 'Note' is deleted. How can I do this? I am bit confused because how does the field know which bit to remove ?

```
-----Helper class--------------
public with sharing class NoteTriggerHelper {
    public static void insertNotesBodyToTextField(List<Note> notes){
        Set<Id> incid = new Set<Id>();
            for(Note n : notes){
                incid.add(n.ParentId);
            }

        List<grc__Incident__c> incidents = [Select Id,Notes__c, (SELECT Id,Title, Body FROM Notes) from grc__Incident__c where Id IN :incid];

            for(grc__Incident__c incident : incidents){
                incident.Notes__c = getNotesString(incident.Notes);
            }

        update incidents;
    }


    private static String getNotesString(List<Note> notes){
        String notesString = '';

            for(Note nt : notes){
                notesString = ' seperator ' + nt.Body + '\n' +notesString;
            }
                return notesString;
    }
}

-----------Trigger--------------
trigger NoteTrigger on Note (after insert, after update) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            NoteTriggerHelper.insertNotesBodyToTextField(Trigger.new);
        }

        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
            NoteTriggerHelper.insertNotesBodyToTextField(Trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be similar to insert trigger but with little difference.

1. Added `after delete` event to Trigger

   ```
   trigger NoteTrigger on Note (after insert, after update, after delete) {
     if(Trigger.isAfter){
       if(Trigger.isInsert){
           NoteTriggerHelper.insertNotesBodyToTextField(Trigger.new);
       }

       if(Trigger.isUpdate){
           NoteTriggerHelper.insertNotesBodyToTextField(Trigger.new);
       }
       if(Trigger.isDelete)
           // Do your stuff here
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Collect parent Id same as you are collecting in `insert` trigger
3. Query the field of the object using the collected parent ID
4. Populate the required field and update the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it using the Process Builder.

Try it if you can, you don't need to write the big coding and it is very easy to understand also.